# How to disable JS file of master page on content pages in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Today i stuck in some problem in asp.net.

Here is the problem:

I have 1 master page and 9-10 content pages.I am using gridview on all pages including Master page.I am applying one js plugin for  custom paging on master page So obviously it shows effect on content pages also.

But i don't want to use paging on some of the content pages but as i have added js file on master page so it dsiplays paging on all content pages.

Please let me know.What i can do to overcome this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You should use a css class selector, on the elements you want the paging add the class and don't add it on any content pages you do not.  Then you do not need to worry about the fact that the JS is included in every page.

Comment: @jammykam  can you please explain more  or any simple example so it clears to me..  thanks

Comment: What plugin are you using? Pls post the HTML and the Javascript you use to initialize the plugin

Comment: I am using this jquery.tablePagination.0.1.js                                             and this is what i am adding on master page to initilaize  plugin.
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
    function () {
       
        $('table').tablePagination({});
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll expand my comment, since there isn't much room there :)

As you have it set up at the moment, an `table` DOM element has the pagination applied to it. If you want only certain tables to have the pagination applied to then:

Add a class to the tables you want the pagination applied to:

```
<table class="pagination"><table>
```

Then initialize your plugin with the selector:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready( function () { 
    $('.pagination').tablePagination({}); 
});
</script>
```

If you don't want the pagination on a particular table, then do not add the css class to it. You can then leave the JS file in your master page without any affect.

Comment: Thanks It was pretty much easy.I  don't know why i didnt figure out this.